# Api Request WSDL Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am trying to make an api connection via wsdl-soap in Python.

Here are the codes I used.

```
import zeep
wsdl = 'http://dev.gittigidiyor.com:8080/listingapi/ws/CategoryService?wsdl'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)


send_data=[{

'cat:getCategories' :[

{
'startOffSet' : 0,
'rowCount' : 4,
'withSpecs':'true',
'withDeepest':'true',
'withCatalog':'true',
'lang':'tr'
}
     ] } ]


print(client.service.getCategories(send_data))
```

The offical [documentation](https://dev.gittigidiyor.com/metotlar/getCategories-CategoryService-soap-anonymous) suggests:

**WSDL Address:** http://dev.gittigidiyor.com:8080/listingapi/ws/CategoryService?wsdl

**Service Method Signature:** CategoryServiceResponse getCategories(int startOffSet, int rowCount, boolean withSpecs, boolean withDeepest, boolean withCatalog, String lang)

**Request Example**

```
<cat:getCategories>
   <startOffSet>0</startOffSet>
   <rowCount>4</rowCount>
   <withSpecs>true</withSpecs>
   <withDeepest>true</withDeepest>
   <withCatalog>true</withCatalog>
   <lang>tr</lang>
</cat:getCategories>
```

However I can't achieve to get any data from the source. I am getting errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maydin/Desktop/z.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(client.service.getCategories(send_data))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/proxy.py", line 42, in __call__
    self._op_name, args, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 115, in send
    options=options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 68, in _create
    serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/definitions.py", line 200, in create
    return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/messages/soap.py", line 65, in serialize
    self.body.render(body, body_value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py", line 191, in render
    self._render_value_item(parent, value, render_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py", line 215, in _render_value_item
    return self.type.render(node, value, None, render_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/types/complex.py", line 253, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/indicators.py", line 241, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py", line 185, in render
    self.validate(value, render_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py", line 236, in validate
    "Missing element %s" % (self.name), path=render_path)
zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element rowCount (getCategories.rowCount)
>>>
```

Any help (new library suggestions, code correction etc.) will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally solved my own problem.. The thing that I have missed is that it was needing an authentication layer.

Here are the codes for those who may need to solve similar problems.

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user_name', 'password')

client = Client('wsdl_url',
    transport=Transport(session=session))


print(client.service.service_name(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3..))
```

Here is the [source](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/transport.html#debugging) I made use of..